# Binding WPF4 Datagrid to Empty Collection

Tags: wpf, datagrid, .net-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I have a collection of objects which I am trying to bind to a DataGrid. When the collection has a lot of objects in it, it works fine. When the collection is empty, however, I see a blank row in the DataGrid, however, I cannot edit it. When I bind it to a collection which has an empty list, then two rows appear, and it is possible to edit the second row with the first empty, even though I have validation. I have tried both an ordinary List<>, and an ObservableCollection<>.

How can I make it so that either the DataGrid can enter into an empty list, or that the DataGrid won't let the user enter into the second blank row?

Comment: The problem with that, is that I still want the user to be able to add rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what its worth, I did figure out what my problem was. Well, I fixed the glitch, but I am not at all sure why it worked.

In the Binding field of the DataGrid, I had Mode=TwoWay on. I thought this was needed, as I wanted the grid to go back to the data, and vice versa. Turns out, removing this fixed the problem.